# Клиент-серверное приложение на Java

Tags: java, исключения, клиент-сервер, сокеты

Доброе время суток всем! Помогите пожалуйста.
Задача состоит в том, чтобы реализовать клиент-серверное приложение для обмена сообщениями.

Клиент:

```
 class ClientThread extends Thread 
 {
        private Socket socket;
        //размер буфера сокета
        private int sz_buf_sock;

        //Буфер для получения данных от сервера
        private BufferedInputStream from_server;
        //Буфер отправки данных серверу
        private BufferedOutputStream to_server;
        //Поток ввода с консоли
        private Scanner scann;
        //
        private ByteArrayOutputStream baos_fs;
        //Буфер для приёма байтов с сервера
        byte[] rec_frmserver;

        //конструктор
        public ClientThread(InetAddress addr) 
        {
           try 
           {
              socket = new Socket(addr, MultiServer.PORT);
           }
           catch (IOException e) 
           {
              System.err.println("Server is not running!");
            }

           try 
           {
               //Инициализация потока получения данных от сервера
               from_server = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
               //Инициализация потока для отправки данных серверу
               to_server = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
               //Поток ввода
                scann = new Scanner(System.in);

               sz_buf_sock = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
               rec_frmserver = new byte[sz_buf_sock];

               start();
           }
           catch (IOException e) 
           {
              // Сокет должен быть закрыт при любой
              // ошибке, кроме ошибки конструктора сокета
              try 
              {
                  socket.close();
              }
              catch (IOException e2) 
              {
                  System.err.println("Socket not closed");
              }
          }
          // В противном случае сокет будет закрыт
          // в методе run()
        }//конец конструктора
        @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    while (true)
                    {   
                        //здесь читаем в бесконечном цикле сообщения, пока не введем "END"  
                        String input_command = scann.next();

                        byte[] inpc_b = input_command.getBytes();
                        System.out.println(input_command);
                        to_server.write(inpc_b);
                        to_server.flush();

                        //если на стороне клиента ввели END, то прекращаем сессию
                        if (input_command.equals("END"))
                            break;  

                        byte[] data;

                        //Читаем данные полученные от сервера
                        int len;
                        //Здесь rec_frmserver - буфер для считывания данных с сервера(его размер - размер буфера сокета) - 8кб
                        while ((len = from_server.read(rec_frmserver)) != -1)
                        {
                                baos_fs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                baos_fs.write(rec_frmserver, 0, len);
                                baos_fs.flush();
                                data = baos_fs.toByteArray();
                                baos_fs.close();
                                String str = new String(data);
                        }
                        //что-то делаем с прочитанными данными
                     }//конец цикла
                }//конец блока try и дальше идёт обработка исключений и закрытие потоков
                catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Server is unreachable..." + '\n');
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally 
            {
                try 
                {
                    to_server.close();
                    from_server.close();
                    socket.close();
                    System.out.println("End session...");   
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    System.err.println("Socket not closed...");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Сервер:

```
class ServeOne extends Thread 
{
    //
    private Socket socket;
    //
    private int sz_buf_sock;
    //Буфер для получения данных от клиента
    private BufferedInputStream from_client;
    //Буфер для отправки данных клиенту
    private BufferedOutputStream to_client;

    //Буфер для полученной команды
    byte[] rec_frclient;

    public ServeOne(Socket s) throws IOException 
    {
       socket = s;
       //Инициализация потока получения данных от клиента
       from_client = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

       //Инициализация потока птправки данных клиенту
       to_client = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

       sz_buf_sock = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
       rec_frclient = new byte[sz_buf_sock];

       //Запускаем поток
       start(); 
    }
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        //Обрабатываем полученные данные
        try 
        {   
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] data;
                //Читаем данные полученные от клиента
                //Здесь rec_frclient - буфер для считывания данных полученных от клиента(его размерность - размер буфера сокета 8 кб)
                int len = from_client.read(rec_frclient);

                data = new byte[len];

                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    data[i] = rec_frclient[i];

                String rec_command = new String(data);

                if (rec_command.equals("END"))
                    break;
                //отправили данные клиенту
                to_client.write(data, 0, data.length);
                to_client.flush();
            }
         }//далее обрабатывае исключения и закрываем потоки
         catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("IO Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                to_client.close();
                from_client.close();
                System.out.println("Client disconnect...");
                socket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Socket not closed...");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Запускаю я это всё дело так:

```
public class MultiServer 
{
    static final int PORT = 8080;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Server Started...");

        try 
        {       
            while (true) 
            {
                //Подключаем клиента
                Socket socket = s.accept();

                try 
                {
                    //Новое соединение
                    ServeOne serveOne = new ServeOne(socket);
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    // Если завершится неудачей, закрывам сокет.
                    // в противном случае, нить закроет его
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally 
        {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

И :

```
public class RunTClient 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
         InterruptedException 
    {
        //Получили адрес локальной машины
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(null);

        new ClientThread(addr);
   }
}
```

Проблема следующая: 
Когда клиент вводи какую-то строку и отсылает Серверу, сервер "виснет" намертво в `int len = from_client.read(rec_frclient);` или в `while ((len = from_server.read(rec_frmserver)) != -1)` и если убить поток вручную, то кидается исключение

```
Server is unreachable...

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:149)
```

Причем, если изначально послать команду "END" то клиент завершит сеанс и всё будет хорошо.
Помогите пожалуйста справиться с этим исключением.
Всё голову уже сломал себе...

Comment: так это нормальное поведение. `while ((len = from_server.read(rec_frmserver)) != -1)` будет работать, пока `read` не вернет `-1`, `read` не вернет `-1` пока из потока можно читать (не закрыто соединение), а если в потоке сейчас нет данных, то `read` будет ждать, пока они не появятся. TCP - потоковый протокол, разбор потока на команды возлагается на прикладной уровень. Можете завернуть чтение в `BufferedReader`, посылать строки, заканчивающиеся на `\n`, и читать через `readLine`. Можете использовать `DataInputStream` и `DataOutputStream`, или встроенную сериализацию.

Comment: @zRrr спасибо за ответ. Попробую следовать Вашим указаниям.